# PHP script showing a blank screen

Tags: php

I have a server setup where a test script with just phpinfo() works fine.

When I try to run my application on it, it shows up as a blank screen.

I am calling index.php from the browser. The first few lines are as:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('codelibrary...
```

Yet, the screen continues to be blank.

---

Edit 1

Here's the structure of the files:

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/codelibrary/inc/user-top.php
/codelibrary/inc/variables.php
/codelibrary/inc/config.php
```

index.php

```
<?php 
require_once('codelibrary/inc/user-top.php'); 
...
```

/codelibrary/inc/user-top.php

```
<?php
require_once("./codelibrary/inc/variables.php"); 
...
```

/codelibrary/inc/variables.php

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
...
```

I thought the referencing here might be a problem, so I changed it to:

```
require_once("./codelibrary/inc/config.php");
```

as well, but no luck.

---

Edit 2

Ah ha! Thanks Col and TopQ for pointing out that I should look at the log file, it says:

> [10-Sep-2010 17:06:02] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Those few lines do nothing that would print something to the screen, no wonder it's blank ... unless you show what's happening further down in your script, it'll be hard to check what's wrong ...

Comment: Hi - there's a lot which the script does / its a full website, so I cant copy paste all that information...

Answer (score 4):

Use "view source" in your browser to see if anything is being written by your script that the browser might not be rendering visibly.

**EDIT**

If you're getting an http 500 response, then you can always do a php lint check on your script from the command line:

```
php -l <filename.php>
```

An extremely useful and oft-forgotten check on the syntax of your code.

Comment: Hi Mark - no, nothing is showing (after fire's changes, just the 500)

Comment: In response to the php -l: Thanks for pointing that out I had no idea! It said: No syntax errors detected in index.php

Comment: Possibly worth doing a php -l lint check on all of the included scripts as well, though if the problem was in one of those I'd have expected you to get a displayed error because the main script has loaded successfully and should be executing to do the includes

Comment: jailshell-3.2$ php -l index.php  
No syntax errors detected in index.php  
jailshell-3.2$ php -l codelibrary/inc/user-top.php  
No syntax errors detected in codelibrary/inc/user-top.php  
jailshell-3.2$ php -l codelibrary/inc/variables.php  
No syntax errors detected in codelibrary/inc/variables.php  
jailshell-3.2$ php -l codelibrary/inc/config.php  
No syntax errors detected in codelibrary/inc/config.php

Answer (score 4):

Try setting display_errors from a `.htaccess` file

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Removed the old .htaccess and set it to what you mentioned, got a "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: hold on - something may be wrong with the above. If I have JUST these 3 lines, I get the 500 error in the phpinfo script! If I dont have a .htaccess, the phpinfo script works fine.

Comment: 500 errors **can** be permission/ownership based - I've sometimes found uploading a script as root to a clients account can cause the script to 500

Comment: Interesting - I didnt know that, but thats not the case here. -rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 86 Sep 10 05:23 .htaccess

Comment: And neither am I root in any of the other files

Comment: what happens if you have ~nothing~ in the script, just <?php ?> does it still 500 ?

Comment: php_flags should be 0s and 1s, not on and off

Comment: fire/Ross - Are you sure I'm supposed to have just these three lines in the .htaccess? Yes, it still gives a 500.

Comment: these 500s most likely from bad .htaccess

Comment: @Col. - I have this now, but its still the same! php_flag display_startup_errors 1
php_flag display_errors 1
php_flag html_errors 1

Comment: just `php_flag display_errors 1` is enough, no need to play with others. and `php_value error_reporing 2048` would be nice too

Comment: your web_server may not support these commands at all. To check an error log is obligatory.

Comment: No luck with the php_value error_reporing 2048. Where would the error log be Col. sir?

Answer (score 2):

Check the PHP error log. Usually syntax error or missing dependencies.

Comment: Sorry - gotta ask - where would that be located?

Comment: @tzm where all other web-server logs being located. you have to consult a server admin/support for that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is possibly the following: The error occurrs before your script runs (i.e. while parsing. Probably some syntax error). Since your script does not run, the error-level cannot be changed dynamically. You need to set `error_reporting` in your `php.ini`, or try fire's suggestion, which should produce equivalent results.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answers here if there is an error present in your script it will fail to set the error levels dynamically.

You can add the proper directives to either the .htaccess file in the current directory, the webserver config or the php.ini file (http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php). You need to prefix those with the php_flag directive a la `php_flag display_errors on`.

If you can't add the commands to the .htaccess files it is most probable that your server config does not allow for overrides for those properties. Consult with the server maintainer for either changing these values, allowing you to override these directives on a per-folder basis and having access to error logs for your virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that this is a script that will be executed by a user outside of your group (the browser/webserver) i would think that the file should be set with permissions 755 as this allows the you to make changes and noone else yet ensures that the browser can execute the script (755 ->  -rwxr-xr-x)